# Django url redirect doesn't work

Tags: python, django

All I want to do is, when I am on the website I click on menu item and then it will redirect me to other page.

I have menu item `Contact` with this code

```
<li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
```

so I created url, view and contact.html page.

In urls.py I have

```
path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

In views.py I have

```
def contact(request):
    return redirect('contact')
```

And then I click on menu item and I get redirected to correct page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact`  but I get this error

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Where do I make mistake? I tried to clear my cookies but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view `contact` is redirecting to your view `contact`. Its a type of infinite recursion.

You probably want to render a page in your `contact` view instead of redirecting again.
The [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) shows the basics for that. Maybe you could look there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used return render(request, 'blog/contact.html') and it works now. Why I cant use redirect? And when to use redirect and when render? Thanks!

Comment: @jv95 `redirect` is mostly used when you want to direct the user to another view function, not the same one.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `Contact`, it redirects you to `views.contact` which again redirects to itself. Therefore, you have an infinite redirect. You can fix this by redirecting to some other view.